# Is it possible to mix C and Python in the same namespace?

Tags: python, distutils

I'd like to write a Python package to wrap a new C library I'm writing - it's all a bit of a learning exercise to be honest. I'd like to call the library `spam` (of course) and the C library is structured like this.

```
Spam/
    lib/
        foo.c
        Makefile
        libspam.a   /* Generated by Makefile */
        libspam.so  /* Generated by Makefile */
```

Let's say foo.c provides a single public function `foo(char * bar)`.At the same time, I want to provide a Python package. I want to provide a wrapper to `foo` and another function, say `safe_foo`, under the same namespace. `safe_foo` is a **Python** function which performs some checks on `bar` then calls `foo`. They could be called like this

```
import spam

file='hello.txt'
foo(file)
safe_foo(file)
```

Is that possible?

A similar situation would be that I develop a Python package and then want to reimplement one function as a C function without breaking the API.

You might be able to see I'm kind of new to Python packaging...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way of doing this is to prefix the C module with an underscore (e.g. `_foo.so`) and then have the Python module named normally (e.g. `foo.py`). `foo` performs an import of `_foo` and contains stubs that call the functions in the C module.